# Can i know when a file is already download in the computer of the user? in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, download, archive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect when browser receives file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download)

I`m making in PHP a excel archive, but i need to know when the download of that arhive is complete to redirect the user to another page??

Can i do it? in PHP, Javascript??

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download for a similar question.

Comment: You can know when you've finished sending the file, but there is no way to tell when the client has finished recieving it (in PHP).

Comment: How are you having the user download the file?

Comment: @JW.: Those answers provide a way for a page to detect when a file download *begins*, not when it finishes.

Comment: I think that's the best you can do. It should be good enough, since the file can continue downloading after you redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this many times by making the target of my form submit an hidden iframe. The target PHP page will do the upload and then I do a PHP echo to write a Javascript block that will call a javascript function on the parent page. This parent function can do your redirect.

I usually display a modal progress bar on the parent page while its waiting for the child page to call the redirect function.